# Retrieve specific value from a JSON blob in MS SQL Server, using a property value?

Tags: json, sql-server, open-json

In my DB I have a column storing JSON. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "views": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "sections": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "isToggleActive": false,
          "components": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "values": [
                "02/24/2021"
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "values": []
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "values": [
                "5393",
                "02/26/2021 - Weekly"
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "5",
              "values": [
                ""
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a migration script that will extract a value from this JSON and store them in its own column.

In the JSON above, in that `components` array, I want to extract the second value from the `component` with an `ID` of "3" (among other things, but this is a good example). So, I want to extract the value "02/26/2021 - Weekly" to store in its own column.

I was looking at the [JSON_VALUE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but I only see examples for specifing indexes for the json properties. I can't figure out what kind of json path I'd need. Is this even possible to do with JSON_VALUE?

EDIT: To clarify, the views and sections components can have static array indexes, so I can use views[0].sections[0] for them. Currently, this is all I have with my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonInfo, '$.views[0].sections[0]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON` to break out the inner array, then filter it with a `WHERE` and finally select the correct value with `JSON_VALUE`

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(components.value, '$.values[1]')
FROM OPENJSON (@jsonInfo, '$.views[0].sections[0].components') components
WHERE JSON_VALUE(components.value, '$.id') = '3'
```